# CORS settings are ignored

Tags: node.js, cors, apollo-client, next.js

I'm having a problem with node.js apparently ignoring my cors settings.
Here are my repos:
[Backend](https://github.com/pawelkrystkiewicz/simple-health-tracker-backend)
[Frontend](https://github.com/pawelkrystkiewicz/simple-health-tracker)

The culprit code in backend:

```
...
//config.CLIENT_URL is 'http://localhost:3000'

const corsOptions: cors.CorsOptions = {
        origin: [String(config.CLIENT_URL)],
        credentials: true,
    };
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));
...
```

Apollo implementation

```
//config.BACKEND_URL_DEV is 'http://localhost:4000/graphql/'
function create (initialState, { getToken }) {
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    credentials: "include",
  uri: `${config.BACKEND_URL_DEV}`,
  })

  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    let token = getToken()
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        cookie: token ? token : ''
      }
    }
  })

  return new ApolloClient({
    connectToDevTools: process.browser,
    ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
  })
}
```

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/dashboard` where I have my query that I know will execute if I'm logged in via `graphql playground` this is the message I receive:

[image]

Funny enough data is received but CORS is preventing it from displaying.
Tested on Opera, Chrome and Firefox DevEdition

[image]

It looks like my backend is setting `*` to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` if the request origin domain is correct.

[image]

Any insight on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try doing `console.log(cors(corsOptions))` and check all the values just to make sure that everything is set right

Comment: This returns `[Function: corsMiddleware]`
But I found solution!

Comment: post it as an answer

Comment: Thank you @evgenifotia you set me on right track!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was with passing `cors` configuration to `apollo-server-express` because `app.use(cors(corsOptions))` does really nothing for this kind of setup.

CORRECT ANSWER:
Move cors config to this section:

```
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsOptions });
```

Found answer thanks to this [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485239/apollo-server-express-cors-issue)