# Apollo Server resetting CORS options

Tags: node.js, express, cors, apollo-server

Apollo server just ignores my CORS layer and applies its own options.

Despite setting the CORS middleware with the option **to reflect** the origin with the following code:

```
    var corsOptions = {
       origin: true,  //This will just copy the request origin and put it in response
       optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
       credentials: true, 
    };
    app.use(cors(corsOptions));

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema, context , playground: true}); 
    await apolloServer.start();

   //Integrate with express
   apolloServer.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/api/graphql', cors: corsOptions});
```

Apollo server just ignores my CORS layer and returns `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "\*"` and because of that I get a CORS error because:

> the value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: If the goal was to make the other post more searchable, you could have suggested an edit to its title rather than writing a whole new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem you will need to provide CORS options directly inside `applyMiddleware` method.
Like this:

```
var corsOptions = {
           origin: true,  //This will just copy the request origin and put it in response
           optionsSuccessStatus: 200, 
           credentials: true, 
        };
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({app, path: '/api/graphql', cors: corsOptions}); //WE ADDED CORS HERE
```

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485239/apollo-server-express-cors-issue) to stack overflow discussion with the same problem.

Also, if interested the [offical documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#applymiddleware) says the following.

[image]